# Load dynamic html text in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm currently creating a mobile app with phonegap and I have to update the content of a div inside my pages. To do this, I can do it two different way :

1. Using [localstorage](http://docs.phonegap.com/fr/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html). Each time the user access to this page, a small JavaScript load this content inside the page.
2. Write directly the new content inside the html page

FYI : The text I have to update can contain between 100 and 500 caracters, and the update will be 3 or 4 pages by month maximum.
So, what do you think is the best way? 1 or 2? Or you have an another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 1 is the best choice, you can retrive text by an ajax call.
Whit solution 2 you must redeploy your application, on ios is an heavy task.